# Creating a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a model called 'Persona' (which belongs_to model User). The user chooses a name in a form and then clicks the create button, so I need the attribute 'name' in the Persona model. I also want the Persona model to have a lower case version of the persona's name, so I need a second attribute 'downcase_name'. For example, the user may choose the persona's name to be Fooey Barman, so the downcase_name would be fooey barman.

My questions is, how do you initialise the downcase_name attribute? Do you put it in the Persona controller? In the new or create methods? Something like:

```
def create
  @persona = Persona.new(persona_params)
  @persona.downcase_name = @persona.name.downcase
  if @persona.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome, " + @persona.name
    redirect_to @persona
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Or do you put it in the model?

```
class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :make_downcase_name
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  private
    def make_downcase_name
      self.downcase_name = name.downcase
    end
end
```

Or perhaps like this?

```
class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :downcase_name, presence: true
end
```

EDIT:

So, am I right in thinking the way to do it is in the model, with a before_save and a validation, like this?:

```
class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :make_downcase_name
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :downcase_name, presence: true
  private
    def make_downcase_name
      self.downcase_name = name.downcase
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the `before_*` callback seems pretty idiomatic. Alternatively, you can also have a service object created in the controller (say `PersonaCreator`) that would handle the logic and set the appropriate attributes on the model.

Note that `before_create` will be called only once, meaning that if the user changes the persona's name later, the callback will not be called. You might want to do something like `before_save` and check whether the name has been changed.

Comment: @fivedigit The blog post cautions against a specific type of callback usage, e.g., callbacks that extend outside of the model's primary responsibilities--which this seems to be, as you state in your answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Are you saying I need to put something like this: downcase_name = name.downcase somewhere in the controller?

Comment: Not really. I'm saying that the use of the before callback is perfectly fine and very common. If you, however, find yourself in a situation where you have a lot of these callbacks, it might be better to move the logic to a separate object (PersonaCreator). This object would be instantiated in the controller, passed the request params. Inside it would create a new instance of the `Persona` model, do the logic (setting the downcase_atribute etc.) and return the unsaved instance back to the controller for saving (so that you can easily handle validation errors).